# PHP keep record of unsuccessful logins

Tags: php

How can I keep a record of the unsuccessful logins to my website? I would like the users browser, IP address, the username that was entered to attempt to login with, and the date and time the login was attempted, all to be stored in a text file. Although this would be easier in a database, I would like it in a text file.

Here is my code:

```
<head>
<title>Landing page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    <div class="loginform">
        <form method="post">
            <input type ='text' name="username">
            <input type ='text' name="password">
            <input type ='submit' name="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</head>
<body>

<?php


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{


$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=user_login",'root','');
$name = $_POST["username"];
$pass = $_POST["password"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = ? AND Password  = ?";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($name,$pass));
$count = $q->rowCount();
if ($count==1) 
{
session_start();
      $_SESSION["logged_in"] = "YES";
      echo "<h1>You are now logged in</h1>";
      echo "<p><a href='secure1.php'>Link to protected file</a></p>";
      echo "<p><a href='secure2.php'>Link to protected file #2</a></p>";
      echo "<p><a href='public.html'>Link to public page</a></p>";
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
while($row = $q->fetch())
{
echo '<p>Welcome <b>'.$row['Firstname'].$row['Lastname'].'</b><br></p>';     //Just to show you output
$_SESSION["Firstname"]  = $row['Lastname'];
}
echo '<p><a href="logout.html">logout</a></p>';
}
else   
{
session_start();
      $_SESSION["logged_in"] = "NO";
      echo "<h1>You are NOT logged in </h1>";
      echo "<p><a href='secure1.php'>Link to protected file</a></p>";
      echo "<p><a href='secure2.php'>Link to protected file #2</a></p>";
      echo "<p><a href='public.html'>Link to public page</a></p>";
      echo "<p>Welcome <b>Guest</b></p>";
}
}
?>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should save it in the database. That will be helpful if in future you need to display or track incorrect logins.

Comment: `file_put_contents` or `fputcsv` depending on requirements

Comment: If you still need to save it in the file then you should create a folder whose name will be userid (in encrypted form)  and save filename by timestamp and in that file you can write the data either using `file_put_contents`, `fputcsv` or `fwrite`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you really want to save all login failed attempts in a text file, then

this

```
    $file = 'failedlogins.txt';
    $entry = "Username: ". $name . " - " . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . " - " . date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A') . "\r\n";
    file_put_contents($file, $entry, FILE_APPEND);
```

or

```
   $f = fopen("failedlogins.txt", "a");
   $entry = "Username: ". $name . " - " . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . " - " . date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A') . "\r\n";
   fwrite($f, $entry);
   fclose($f);
```

it will output on the file something like:

```
Username: Superman - 127.0.0.1 - Thursday 18th of June 2015 11:59:08 AM
Username: Batman - 127.0.0.1 - Thursday 18th of June 2015 11:59:08 AM
```

Comment: The example using `file_put_contents` won't do what you want - you're loading it, appending the data, and then appending the result back to the file. Drop the `file_get_contents` line - the option `FILE_APPEND` will do the appending for you.

Comment: you're right.. perils of copying sample code and editing in a hurry. thanks.

Comment: Change `$entry .=` to `$entry =` as well, otherwise you're appending to `$entry` variable.

Comment: missed that.. you could have edit it yourself. but thanks anyway.

Comment: If you have time - can you show me how to display successful log ins in a database table? Thanks for the answer :)